# How to write Spring MethodInterceptor for SelfPopulatingCache

Tags: spring

How to Implement a method return data caching interceptor using SelPopulatingCache to cache the object graph for subsequent calls to the any method.

Please suggest me .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You keep asking about this, and your questions are still far too vague for anyone to have a hope of answering them.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ehcache-spring-annotations](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/) they provide an easy annotation based way to controll the cache.

Comment: Ralph: I dont need annotation based in my requirement,I want to create method based selfpopulatingcache.

Comment: @raj: and how do you want to specifiy which method should be cached? - in ehcache-spring-annotations is this done with annotations. The cache itselve is based on Eh-Cache

Comment: Using MethodIntercetor through aop i done with Cache,but here i want to use SelfPopulatingCache instead of Cache using MethodInterceptor.

Comment: ehcache-spring-annotations Supports use of SelfPopulatingCache via annotations